# Webpack, require is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack

Getting an error when running my webpack-built React app - the error is as follows:

```
webpack-internal:///1495:3
var crypto = require('crypto');
             ^

TypeError: require is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///1495:3:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/build/main.js:9739:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/path/to/project/build/main.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///1494:1:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/build/main.js:9733:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/path/to/project/build/main.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///692:8:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/build/main.js:4515:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/path/to/project/build/main.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///1491:12:23)
```

I can't figure out which module this error is coming from. I am running my project by this command:

```
NODE_ENV=development nodemon --watch build/ build/main.js
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const webpackConfig = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../src/entry.js')],
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
      path.join(__dirname, '../server'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          context: 'src/app/assets/',
          outputPath: 'dist/',
          name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
          //limit: 10000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    mysql: 'empty',
    __dirname: true
  },
  plugins: [
    // hot reload new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
        API_HOST: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_HOST),
        API_PORT: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_PORT)
      },
    }),

  ],
  externals: ['mysql', 'bindings']
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV ===  'development') {
  webpackConfig.devtool = 'eval-source-map'
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

The file is being built with this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --display-error-details --config webpack/webpack.config.js
```

The version of webpack I am using is 3.0.0.

Comment: Why are you running the app with `nodemon`?

Comment: What would you recommend instead? I can run it using webpack-dev-server but I'm not entirely sure it's necessary for my project. The problem seems to be in the build file anyway. Correct me if I'm wrong though - I wouldn't say I'm a beginner here but also by no means an expert.

Comment: Using `webpack-dev-server` to run code in development as always a better option than using custom code. In my projects, I use the `webpack` command only to the code to be used in production. Also, how does the `main.js` even work in a way you can build it with webpack and then run it using nodemon, are you using it with a server, such as express?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak ok thanks, honestly never given it much thought. Yes, it's a React app and associated back-end, each running Express servers. At some point they will be split up into seperate projects but for now it works fine.

Comment: If the react app is separated from the backend (which you should do if possible), `webpack-dev-server` is probably the best option you can use in development. It's a static server which will automatically recompile your files using the same webpack config so you can be sure the code you're using in development will run the same in production, minus the environment specific conditions, if any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error importing superagent in React code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669533/error-importing-superagent-in-react-code)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a `require` in your bundle, it means that some ES6 file has not been transpiled by Babel.

I can see that you exclude `node_modules` from `babel-loader`...

Can you try removing the exclusion and see if it's any better?

Also, can you search for "require('crypto')" in all files arborescence?

Last, you say that it's a React app but `babel-loader` only transpiles `.js` files, not `.jsx`... Can you try changing loader's `test` to `/\.jsx?$/` ?